# Do I need more space between my AC unit and bed headboard?

Tags: air-conditioning

I'm unsure whether I can place an AC unit in my bedroom window because the headboard comes up right against the window. There would only be about 5 inches of space between the AC unit and the headboard. Would that be a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window unit ac vents are places on top so not a problem. first problem will be to make sure your curtains do not block the air intake in front of the window unit. so need to have good air flow to the intake or it will freeze the unit. next problem is that the unit sits inside your window so this will stick out from flush of your window about 5 inches. from your window to your wall is 2 inches. the window unit will stick out pass your wall quite a bit. go to local store and look at one. you will see where the window will sit on the unit and you will be able to go from there